# Display Yens in QuickReport

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-6, quickreports, currency-formatting

When I print a Currency field, I get '\0' instead of then Yen-sign (my regional settings are set to Japanese Format)

How can I display Yens in a Report in Delphi 6? (I can not use another version of Quick Reports)

Any idea is welcomed!

Comment: So you are using character $5C and it won't appear in your reports even though it works in the Delphi form? What is the character value  of the Yen symbol that you are using?  You are using the Japanese codepage in Windows (codepage 932)?

Comment: Name of the font in use is also interesting.

Comment: For display I use TQRDBText through AMOUNT: TCurrencyField from Paradox Table.
I resolved my problem. I had to write Font.CharSet := SHIFTJIS_CHARSET; Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fixed the problem by doing

```
Font.Charset:= SHIFTJIS_CHARSET;
```

An alternative option is:

You can use the `OnPrint` event of the number you're printing and prefix the `¥` symbol.

Like so:

```
procedure TForm1.QRDBAnAmountPrint(sender: TObject; var Value: string);
begin
  //If the number doesn't have a currency symbol.
  Value:= '¥ '+Value;

  //If the number does have a currency symbol
  Value:= StringReplace(Value, "textforwrongsymbol", "¥");
end;
```